# DataGridView not showing the data after inserting in local database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have created an app linked to a local database. It works well, but the only problem is that after I press the insert button, data is inserted in db, but it is not showed in the GridView, only after I close and reopen the application. How can I make it show the data right after I press the button which inserts the values? Thanks !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;

namespace Gradinita
{
    public partial class Grupa : Form
    {
        string nume = "";
        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        public Grupa(string nume)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.nume = nume;

        }

        private void Grupa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'grupeDataSet8.copii' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.copiiTableAdapter2.Fill(this.grupeDataSet8.copii);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'grupeDataSet7.copii' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.copiiTableAdapter1.Fill(this.grupeDataSet7.copii);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'grupeDataSet3.copii' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.copiiTableAdapter.Fill(this.grupeDataSet3.copii);
            var connString = (@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\Grupe.sdf");
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "SELECT * FROM grupe WHERE Nume='" + nume + "'";
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    label1.Text = dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    label2.Text = dataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    label3.Text = dataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    label4.Text = dataTable.Rows[0][3].ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
        }
    }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = ("1");
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = ("0");
            }
            textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text)).ToString();
            var connString = (@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\Grupe.sdf");
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "INSERT INTO copii(prezenta, Nume, Prenume, Program, Taxa, Achitat, Diferenta) VALUES('" + label5.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox4.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox5.Text.Trim() + "', '"+ textBox6.Text.Trim()+"', '"+ textBox1.Text.Trim() +"');";
                    MessageBox.Show(query);
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();  //not working obviously

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: dataGridView1.ReBind();

Comment: you should Select Data and bind datagridview again.

Comment: It shows an error because System.DataGrindView does not contain a definition for "ReBind". Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-query the data and rebind the datatable.

Something like:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = SomeDataTableSource;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataGridView does not contain a definition for dataBind. Why?

Comment: ah, sorry your using System.Windows.Forms, try instead dataGridView1.SetDataBinding(SomeDataSet, "TableName");

Comment: Same. No definition for SetDataBinding.

Comment: hmm. ok final idea then if you have a definition for the dataGridView1.DataSource try dataGridView1.DataSource = SomeDataTableSource;  dataGridView1.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass this by re-adding the grid to the control. First, you copy the grid in a variable, then you remove it from the parent control, and then you add the variable to the controls of that control.

```
var grid = dataGridView1.Parent.Controls["dataGridView1"];
var ctr = dataGridView1.Parent;
ctr.Controls.Remove(dataGridView1);
ctr.Controls.Add(grid);
```

It's not tested and I might have mistaken some names cause i don't have a VS installed here, but you get the idea. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me. You can also try dataGridView1.Refresh() - which it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, it's only Parent, I told you I have no VS :P I edited the code

Comment: Have you tried the refresh method too? Also, be more specific with the errors. And don't just copy/paste what people write to you, try to understand it, I told you that the code is not tested cause I just wrote it down here.

Comment: I understand that. And yes, tried refresh method, but useless.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the refresh in the code. Detail the errors please.

Comment: No. That's because I have removed it, because it won't worked. Error: `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Remove(System.Windows.Forms.Control)' has some invalid arguments ` and `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'`

Comment: Works. But still not showing the data after button click . Pisses me off, damn.

Comment: Try closing the connection `conn.Close()` right before the refresh line and if this doesn't work, take the dataTable inside the Grupa_Load method and make it global. Then, just before the refresh, bind the dataGridView again. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88585/discussion-between-andrei-micu-and-user3348368).